# Как получить список файлов в папке и подпапках?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Собственно, вопрос в названии темы.

по пути `./app/templates/data/` работает, но не видит файлы в подпапках, а по шаблону `./app/templates/data/**/` вообще не работает.

```js
.pipe(data(function(file) {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./app/templates/data/**/' + path.basename(file.path).replace('.html', '.json')));
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать рекурсивно

```
function givMeFiles (dir, files){
    
  files = files || [];
    var allFiles = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (var i =0; i<allFiles.length; i++){
        var name = dir + '/' + allFiles[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            givMeFiles (name, files);
        } else {
            files.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files;
};
givMeFiles ("C:\\Users\\Guest\\myProject\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким образом, если есть другие варианты, напишите пожалуйста!

```js
.pipe(data(function(file) {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('.\\app\\templates\\data\\' + file.relative.replace('.html', '.json')));
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```js
.pipe(data(function(file) {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./app/templates/data/**/*' + path.basename(file.path).replace('.html', '.json')));
}))
```

Comment: разницы нет, что так /**/ что так /**/*, fs.readFileSync не умеете читать ссылки по такому шаблону